# Method of Moments query

Tags: probability

I don't follow the section of the solution highlighted. I am attempting to compute the parameters of a gamma function by the Method of moments.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample variance $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$ is zero, the computation "fails" in the sense that $\tilde\alpha$ becomes infinite. You might think this could potentially be a problem and that assuming $\tilde\alpha>0$ is invalid, or at least makes for an incomplete solution.

However, for the variance to be zero, you need $X_1=\cdots=X_n$, and the probability of that happening by chance (assuming the $X_i$ are independently drawn from an continuous distribution) is zero.

In statistics, probability zero is used instead of "impossible", but referred to as "almost never happens" rather than "impossible". Technically, it is *possible* to draw the same $X_i$. In fact, $X_1=\cdots=X_i=x$ is no more impossible than any other $X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n$. However, we can choose to disregard any particular set of outcomes, usually a set of special cases, as long as this has probability zero since that set of outcomes will not contribute to any probability or expected value.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to divide by $\frac{1}{n}\sum (X_i -\bar{X})^2$ as this expression is almost surely positive. If the $X_i$ were real numbers or some discretely distributed random variables, this would be not the case and you would have to think about not dividing by zero. But as the $X_i$ are Gamma distributed, you don't have to worry. You will almost surely not divide by zero.